# How can we add a Chrome extension to someone else's Electron app?

Tags: electron

There are many desktop applications these days that use [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) and some of them would really benefit from having access to Chrome extensions.

How can a user add a Chrome extension to a downloaded Electron application?

Answer (score -2):

Begin by locating installation directory for your desired Electron app on-device; once found, proceed by creating a fresh sub-directory identified as 'extensions' within its installation directory.

At this next stage simply transfer all files regarding selected Chrome Extension into this freshly created 'extensions' folder.

Thereafter, open up main.js or index.js files (depending on which serves as primary script) inside initialized BrowserWindow – now search and head towards webPreferences object section.

In order activate selected Chrome Extension within your Electron app, turn preloadExtensions property to true inside webPreferences updated settings.

Following this avail session.defaultSession's loadExtension method wherein we specify directory path relevant to our included Chrome Extension earlier.

Lastly, remember to save any relevant changes made before restarting your Electron app.

Once ready you can then begin accessing all required functionality coming from added Chrome Extension through your new Electron application without hindrance!

Please note that there may be periodic compatibility and functional clashes between specific browser extensions and Eletron Apps that you may need to work through - as such we strongly advise thorough testing before the extension is deployed at full scale via the resultant application.across larger deployments in order to ensure smooth functioning and proper integration in use over time.

Comment: Looks like more ChatGPT

Comment: Why do you think that if i may ask.

Comment: @DavidW: That may be a false positive. ChatGPT has perfect spelling and grammar. That is not the case here. For instance, *[Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework))* was misspelt (one instance). Though answers before December 2022 were less verbose and the phrasing in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462435/is-it-possible-to-combine-array-with-strings-in-php/76462605#76462605) looks like ChatGPT.

Comment: @PeterMortensen maybe. Some of their earlier answers look more definite to me which probably influenced my perception of this answer. My strong suspicion is that this answer is largely generated. But I could be wrong

Comment: @DavidW: It could be a mix: All but the last paragraph generated by ChatGPT. The last paragraph is one very long sentence. I think ChatGPT would use shorter sentences, e.g., three main clauses in that paragraph. I agree yesterday's answers look suspicious.