# Complete email addresses in a flat array using static domains (only where missing), then implode

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, email-address

I have written a script (I'm quite new to PHP) which will take a list of elements as an input and checks whether it’s only a username or it contains username+domain name (I mean email).

If it’s only a username, then it will append '@test.com' into that username and combine all the strings together to send an email notification.

```
$recipients = array("kumar", "ram@test.com", "ravi", "rob@example.com");

$with_domain = array();
$without_domain = array();

$exp = "/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/";
foreach ($recipients as $user) {
    if(preg_match($exp, $user)) {
        array_push($with_domain, $user);
    } else {
        array_push($without_domain, $user);
    }
}

$without_domain_new = implode("@test.com", $without_domain)."@test.com";

print_r($with_domain);
print_r($without_domain_new);
echo "<br>";

$r = implode("", $with_domain);
$s = $without_domain_new.$r;

print "Email notification need to be sent to: $s";
```

Here script works as expected. But is the line `$r = implode("", $with_domain); $s = $without_domain_new.$r;` really required?

Is it be possible to merge array and strings in PHP? I mean, is it possible to merge `$with_domain` and `$without_domain_new` and store it to `$s` as a string?

Comment: That seems complicated. If you're just going to add the same domain name on the end of any name that doesn't have one, why not do it in the `array_push` in the starting loop? `array_push($without_domain, $user . "@test.com")` would do the trick. Is there even any need to have the separate arrays?

Comment: No, I want all the elements (after adding ‘@test.com’) to be in ‘$s’.

Comment: ^ Then implode the single array once you've built it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$emails = array_map(function ($username) {
    return preg_match("/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/", $username) ? $username : $username . '@test.com';
}, $recipients);
```

It will give you an array with all email addresses you want.

And then you can use `implode('', $emails)` or maybe `implode(',', $emails)` to convert an array to a string for sending notification.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest since you're starting out, try simplifying the code a bit. Example: `array()` is not necessary. Rather just use `[]`. I also prefer single quotes, but that's just me :) So your array:

```
$recipients = array("kumar", "ram@test.com", "ravi", "rob@example.com");
```

Becomes:

```
$recipients = ['kumar', 'ram@test.com', 'ravi', 'rob@example.com'];
```

Also `array_push` is usually used when multiple array items are needing to be pushed towards and array, so a simple `$array[] = 'something';` will suffice here.

***Now onto the actual issue at hand.***

You can simplify what you're trying to achieve with this:

```
$recipients = ['kumar', 'ram@test.com', 'ravi', 'rob@example.com'];
$users = [];

foreach ($recipients as $user) {
    if (preg_match("/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/", $user)) {
        $users[] = $user;
    } else {
        $users[] = $user . '@test.com';
    }
}

print 'Email notification need to be sent to: ' . implode(', ', $users);
```

That way, you're adding all the users to the `$users` array and appending `@test.com` to the ones who need appending. Dealing with *one* array, since you're interested in *one* result, i.e., users needing to be emailed :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create multiple arrays to store the intermediate results and do multiple implode's to get the final result. You can map your array with strings so that they all have the right format, and then implode only once.

When using implode with an empty string (which is the default), your result will have all strings concatenated without a delimiter and you can not tell the email addresses apart.

If your email addresses can contain only a single `@` char, you can [update the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/0S7xO9/1) using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to exclude matching an `@` char

```
$recipients = ["kumar","ram@test.com","ravi","rob@example.com"];
$pattern = "/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/";
$s = implode(
    ", ",
    array_map(fn($user) => preg_match($pattern, $user) ? $user : $user . "@test.com", $recipients)
);

echo $s;
```

Output

```
kumar@test.com, ram@test.com, ravi@test.com, rob@example.com
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/QSRQl).

Answer (score 0):

It seems simplest to me that you just use `preg_replace()` to add an email domain to any string that doesn't have it, then join the results with a comma and a space.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ABCI9))

```
$recipients = [
    "kumar",
    "ram@test.com",
    "ravi",
    "rob@example.com"
];

echo implode(
         ', ',
         preg_replace(
             '/^[^@]+$/',
             '$0@test.com',
             $recipients
         )
     );
```

Result:

```
kumar@test.com, ram@test.com, ravi@test.com, rob@example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to merge the arrays and strings into a single string, you can use the implode() function to convert the arrays to strings and then concatenate them together. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<?php
$recipients = array("kumar", "ram@test.com", "ravi", "rob@example.com");

$with_domain = array();
$without_domain = array();

$exp = "/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/";
foreach ($recipients as $user) {
    if (preg_match($exp, $user)) {
        array_push($with_domain, $user);
    } else {
        array_push($without_domain, $user);
    }
}

$without_domain_new = implode("@test.com ", $without_domain) . "@test.com";
$combined = implode(", ", array_merge($with_domain, [$without_domain_new]));

print "Email notification needs to be sent to: $combined";
?>
```

In this updated code, $without_domain_new is created by using implode() to concatenate the elements of the $without_domain array with the string "@test.com " (note the space after .com) as the delimiter. Then, the $with_domain array and $without_domain_new are merged using array_merge() to combine them into a single array. Finally, the merged array is imploded with ", " (comma followed by a space) as the delimiter to create the desired string, which is stored in $combined.

Now, when you print $combined, it will display the merged string containing all the email addresses with and without domains, separated by commas and spaces.

Comment: Your four answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.